# Omit domain part from username using realmd

Tags: linux, active-directory, realmd

I'm experimenting with joining my Linux machine to an AD domain, using [`realmd`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/realmd/docs/realm.html). Everything went very well (after [enabling automatic home directory creation](https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/578737-linux-mint-17-realmd-and-automatic-home-directory-creation)).

Now I can login as `jreinhart@domain.com` with my domain password. `getent passwd jreinhart@domain.com` shows:

```
jreinhart@domain.com:*:136601010:136600513:jreinhart:/home/domain.com/jreinhart:/bin/bash
```

However, when I `ls` my files, they look like:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 jreinhart@domain.com domain users@domain.com 123 [date] filename
```

It seems like having such a long user name and primary group name might get annoying.

Aside from `root` and the standard usernames, I have no need for other local accounts on this machine. **Is there a way to omit the domain part of user and group names?**

Answer (score 2):

You can change this behavior with the following (realm-specific) option in [`/etc/realmd.conf`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/realmd/docs/realmd-conf.html) (which does not exist by default):

```
fully-qualified-names

    This option is on by default. If turned off then realm user and group
    names are not qualified their name. This may cause them to conflict
    with local user and group names.

        [domain.example.com]
        fully-qualified-names = no
        # fully-qualified-names = yes
```